# iTunes 11: Where are my podcasts?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Ok, unless I'm missing something, I can't see my podcasts anymore? The only place they appear is in a new "Podcasts" playlist, which isn't much use to me for keeping track of episodes and subscriptions.

Am I just being blind? :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to recheck the Podcasts checkbox in the menu `iTunes | Preferences... | General tab`.  [OSX Daily suggests](http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/29/5-tips-make-itunes-look-normal/) that it may be unchecked by default. Once checked, podcasts should appear under Library rather than as a playlist.

Comment: It seems, even though there are episodes in a playlist, that I have to add every single episode from scratch since I upgraded :(

Answer (score 2):

If you hit <kbd>option-command-s</kbd> it will bring up the sidebar. You will see your Podcasts there.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have podcasts showing, using the dropdown upper right, if you switch to list view (weirdly located as one of 3 options in center of entire window, under "progress bar"), if you then click the twirl-down arrow for a podcast, a big gray arrow will automatically show if there are un-dowloaded episodes of that podcast. Click that, and a window will ask you if you want to download all episodes, which obviously you do. It all seems a little odd and seems like Apple needs to work on tis a bit more.

Comment: Question is how to get the podcasts showing